# Spell check in MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have the following Public Function below that performs a spell check of the active Access form when called upon. I have a couple of hidden fields and the function breaks because it can't set the focus on those fields. How do I get around this?

```
Public Function SpellChecker()

Dim ctrl As Control

Dim frm As Form

Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
 If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
   If Len(ctrl) > 0 Then
     With ctrl
      .SetFocus
      .SelStart = 0
      .SelLength = Len(ctrl)
     End With

     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling

   End If
 End If

Next

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Function
```

Comment: Either unhide or don't spell check those.

Comment: Use the `.visible` property and skip if not visible

Comment: The .visible property worked for me. Thank you!!